# Linear PDE with Variable Coefficients Help

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I would like to find the closed-form solution (for $x > 0$) to

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = a \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} +b \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + (cx+d) u,$$
    $$u(0,\,x) = 1,\;\; \frac{\partial u(t,\,0)}{\partial x} = 0,$$

where $a,\,b,\,c,\,d \in \mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$ are arbitrary constants. Though I looked in several books, I was not able to find a suitable approach with the given boundary/initial conditions. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Since your pde is second-order in $x$, surely you need an additional boundary condition.  And do you have any reason to believe there is a closed-form solution?

Comment: Hi Robert,

Thank you for your reply. I just clarified the original problem by adding the remark that we are working only with the positive half-line. If so, would these 2 boundary/initial conditions be sufficient? Thanks again!

Comment: That in itself is not sufficient.  Some appropriate condition at $+\infty$ might work.

Answer (score 2):

Let 
\begin{align}
u(x,t) = e^{- \lambda t} f(x)
\end{align}
to obtain the differential equation, in $x$, 
\begin{align}
a f^{''} + b f^{'} + (c x + d + \lambda) f = 0.
\end{align}
Now let 
\begin{align}
f(x) = e^{-(b x)/(2a)} g(x)
\end{align}
to obtain the differential equation
\begin{align}
g^{''} + \left( \frac{c}{a} \ x + \frac{d + \lambda}{a} - \frac{b^{2}}{4 a^{2}} \right) g = 0.
\end{align}
This is Airy's differential equation in a slightly different form and has the solution
\begin{align}
g(x) = c_{1} Ai\left(- \frac{\beta + \alpha x}{(-\alpha)^{2/3}} \right) + 
c_{2} Bi\left(- \frac{\beta + \alpha x}{(-\alpha)^{2/3}} \right), 
\end{align}
where $\alpha = c/a$ and $\beta = (d+\lambda)/a - b^{2}/(4 a^{2})$.

The general solution is then 
\begin{align}
u(x,t) = e^{- \lambda t} \ e^{- bx/2a} \left[ c_{1} Ai\left(- \frac{\beta + \alpha x}{(-\alpha)^{2/3}} \right) + 
c_{2} Bi\left(- \frac{\beta + \alpha x}{(-\alpha)^{2/3}} \right) \right]
\end{align}
where $\alpha = c/a$ and $\beta = (d+\lambda)/a - b^{2}/(4 a^{2})$.

The remainder of the problem is using the initial conditions to find the constants $c_{1}$, $c_{2}$ and the separation constant $\lambda$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I will study this carefully. Like Robert mentioned, it seems like we might need an additional boundary condition???

Comment: @Bryon If the solution is bounded for $x \geq 0$ then this would satisfy as another condition. This would suggest that $c_{2} = 0$ in order for $u(x,t) << \infty$ for $x \geq 0$.

Comment: $u(x,0)=1$ is going to be impossible, because the exponential function is not a linear combination of $Ai$ and $Bi$.  You need to, in some sense, combine these for infinitely many different $\lambda$'s: that's essentially what the Laplace transform approach does.

Comment: Thank you again for your replies! I was wondering if I could ask a related question: in "Handbook of Linear Partial Differential Equations" by Polyanin, Section 1.3.3 suggests a certain transformation that changes the PDE above into the heat equation. However, the boundary condition involving ∂u∂x   seems problematic. If you also have access to this book, would you please let me know if the approach Polyanin suggests might work? Thank you so much!

Comment: How did you know to find that form of solution for $f$? @Leucippus

Comment: @Tyler Usually an exponential will eliminate a first derivative term when dealing with the form $a f'' + b f'$. One could also try a form like $f = p \cdot g$ where $p$ is the term that will cancel the first derivative.

Answer (score 1):

The Laplace transform with respect to $t$ leads to the differential equation
$$sY \left( x \right) -1=a\;{\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{
{\rm d}{x}^{2}}}Y \left( x \right) +b\;{\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}x}}Y
 \left( x \right) + (  c x+d)\; Y \left( x \right) 
$$
which has solutions involving Airy functions and integrals of Airy functions times exponentials (not surprising since the Airy differential equation is $w'' = x w$).  I would be surprised if the inverse
Laplace transform could be expressed in closed form.

Comment: Thank you again for your replies! I was wondering if I could ask a related question: in "Handbook of Linear Partial Differential Equations" by Polyanin, Section 1.3.3 suggests a certain transformation that changes the PDE above into the heat equation. However, the boundary condition involving $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ seems problematic. If you also have access to this book, would you please let me know if the approach Polyanin suggests might work? Thank you so much!

Comment: I do not have that book.  I would be quite surprised if you could get the heat equation.  I know how to get rid of the $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}$, but not the $(cx+d) u$.  It must be quite some transformation if it can turn an Airy function into something like $\exp(-x^2)$.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late response. This is what the Polyanin book suggests:

Consider
$$u(t,\,x) = w(t,\,z) \exp\left( ctx-\frac{b}{2a}x+\frac{1}{3}ac^2t^3 + \left(d-\frac{b^2}{4a}\right)t \right),\;\;\;z=x+act^2$$.

Then
$$\partial_t w = a \partial_{zz} w$$.

However, the book makes no mention of boundary conditions. I would appreciate any tips!

Thanks,
Bryon